# How to implement AdMob after iAd fails mediation

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, iad, simulator

I implemented for iAds to works in bannerViewDidLoadAd method and then I implemented for AdMob to work in didFailToReceiveAdWithError method. However, on the same view controller I have a GameOver method where I want ad to appear. Only iAds load on GameOver method, AdMob doesn't. Also, when iAds fail to load AdMob doesn't load.  It seems to me since I added the GADBannerView programmatically onto Storyboards the game never responds to  _bannerView.hidden=YES or NO. Since i Added the ADBannerView from Object Library in Xcode, the game only responds to iAdBanner.hidden=YES or NO. Why doesn't AdMob respond to a programmatically added Ad banner?

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
  [iAdBanner setAlpha:1];
   iAdBanner.hidden=NO;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 [self.iAdBanner setDelegate:self];
 _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
  }

 -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
 [iAdBanner setAlpha:0];
 iAdBanner.hidden=YES;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
  _bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait]; 

  _bannerView=[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
   self.bannerView.adUnitID=@"UNIT-ID";
   self.bannerView.rootViewController=self;
   [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];  
   self.bannerView.delegate = self;   
   GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];
   request.testDevices= @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];  
   [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];

     }
```

Comment: Can you post your code? There's very little we can do to help otherwise.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint, can you confirm that the line `[self.bannerView loadRequest:request];` does actually get executed?

Comment: The above code is in my 2nd ViewController and 1st ViewController where the intro of game is. If I receive an AdMob ad on 1st VC then on 2nd VC, i'll never receive any type of test ads ever in my GameOver and ViewDidLoad screens. However, if on 1st VC I receive an iAd, then on 2nd VC in GameOver and ViewDidLoad, i ALWAYS receive iAd ads. However, if then i click back to 1st VC from 2nd VC, only then I always start receiving only AdMob test banner. If I turn off game and then back on again, same thing always happens. Why is this happening? Why does 1st VC affect type of ads on 2nd VC?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you probably shouldn't be actually assigning delegates within a failure callback. You probably want to do all `setDelegate: self` calls inside `viewDidLoad`. Another possibility is that you have frequency capping turned on.. did you set AdMob or iAd to only show X ads per day? If so you may just be running out.

Comment: I never set adMob or iAd to show any specific number of test ads, don't even know where to set that.